# Get the longest non-glob string at the start of a string

Tags: git, filenames, glob

I'm trying to create a script to convert from $GIT_DIR/info/exclude to .gitignore files. I'd like to put the .gitignore files as close to the pattern target as possible, meaning that a glob like `/a/b/*/*.c` should be put in `/a/b/.gitignore`. To do this accurately, I need something which can return the longest substring from the start which is uniquely identified, based on `man glob`. Does there exist anything like this, preferably something which is portable across *nixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - By iterating over `dirname "$string"` until `[ -e "$string" ]` succeeds. The resulting script can be found in a [blog post](http://l0b0.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/n-way-git-synchronization-with-extra-cheese/#git-ignore).